# Get Video Duration in GeckoFX

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I have created a Window From Application. Then added GeckoFX from nuget package. Added the control in the form. I am loading a video from youtube.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHtfB_zCJFE");
        }
    }
}
```

when i close the form, i want to get the duration i played the video.

Its not just youtube. Any video played, i want to get the duration played.

Comment: _Any video played, i want to get the duration played_ - I doubt very much this is possible, What if you paused the video, or played it at double speed, or stopped it and went to lunch? The 'browser' (in this case Gecko) won't measure how long it took you to actually watch the video. Now if you want to get the actual video _length_, that may be possible, maybe with the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

Comment: whether i pause, double speed or whatever. when i close the form i want to get the value, suppose 5:00/10:00 or 8:45. Is there a way to get the value by HTML element ?

Comment: Try `geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("ytp-bound-time-right")[0].TextContent`